# Prevent colon in URL from changing to %3A

Tags: html, forms, url

Is it possible to have a colon from a form go into a link to populate a form on a new page? At the moment the link keeps changing to %3A.

For example, current: http://www.test.com/?field=123%3A456

Trying to have: current: http://www.test.com/?field=123:456

Answer (score 3):

You can't.
You need to decode the parameters

for serverside php you can use

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

```
$field = urldecode($_GET['field'])
```

for javascript you can use

```
decodeURIComponent('123%3A456');
```